# Input se ve sobre navbar

Tags: html, css

tengo el siguiente problema...
Tengo el siguiente formulario en bootstrap
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui se ve normal, pero al momento de subir, el elemento input Telefono de Casa y Número Celular, hacen lo siguiente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como lo puedo solucionar? Intente con la propiedad de css de z-index: -1; pero al momento de poner esa propiedad ya no me deja escribir ni seleccionarlo, entonces no se como resolverlo, lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: Podrías intentar darle un `z-index: 2;` (o más) al container del navbar para que se sobre ponga sobre los demás elementos.

Comment: No me ha funcionado :(

Comment: Tendrías que mostrar el código de ambos elementos. Edita tu pregunta y agrega código porque es difícil saber que está pasando sin ver el código.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue poner un

```
<div class="clase"> <nav> </div>
```

Dando

```
z-index: 100;
```

a "clase".

Comment: Agrega el código que has intentado en la pregunta, y proporciona más detalles en tu respuesta. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._ Además, tal como está redactada la pregunta, solo te será de utilidad a ti, y no para otros que tengan un problema similar. Lee [answer] y [ask].